# Verification method not firing after second ClientHello with OpenSSL memory BIOs

Tags: c++, openssl, dtls

I am writing a native DTLS module for NodeJS using OpenSSL. It uses memory BIOs so node's own sockets can be used to control the flow of data. Everything seems to be working but I am running into some problems with the DOS mitigation.

According to the spec, the initial ClientHello sent to the server should be rejected and the server will send a HelloVerifyRequest containing a cookie to be resent back from the client. This all works fine but when the client sends back the second ClientHello, for some reason the DTLSv1_listen() call is causing my cookie generation method to fire a second time instead of the cookie verification method. Strangely enough, if I send back the second HelloVerifyRequest (exact same length and content as the first) I end up with a ClientHello that seems to trigger the verification method.

Here's a small test I've written to illustrate the kind of thing I'm doing (not exactly, skipped some stuff like importing the cert/key, result code checking for read/writes after calling handshake, freeing memory etc).

```
TEST(New, Test) {
    // Init context
    auto ctx = SSL_CTX_new(DTLS_method());
    SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(ctx, "ALL:!ADH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:@STRENGTH");
    SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx, SSL_VERIFY_NONE, [](int ok, X509_STORE_CTX * context) { return 1; });
    SSL_CTX_set_cookie_generate_cb(ctx, [](SSL * ssl, unsigned char * cookie, unsigned int * cookie_len) { 
        return 1; 
        });
    SSL_CTX_set_cookie_verify_cb(ctx, [](SSL * ssl, const unsigned char * cookie, unsigned int cookie_len) { 
        return 1; 
        });

    // Init connections
    auto client = SSL_new(ctx);
    auto client_rbio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    auto client_wbio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    SSL_set_bio(client, client_rbio, client_wbio);
    SSL_set_connect_state(client);

    auto server = SSL_new(ctx);
    auto server_rbio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    auto server_wbio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    SSL_set_bio(server, server_rbio, server_wbio);
    SSL_set_accept_state(server);

    std::vector<unsigned char> data;

    // Client Hello, no cookie
    SSL_do_handshake(client);
    auto data_len = BIO_ctrl_pending(client_wbio);
    data.resize(data_len);
    BIO_read(client_wbio, data.data(), data.size());

    ASSERT_EQ(data[13], 1);

    // Hello Verify Request
    BIO_write(server_rbio, data.data(), data.size());
    DTLSv1_listen(server, NULL);
    data_len = BIO_ctrl_pending(server_wbio);
    data.resize(data_len);
    BIO_read(server_wbio, data.data(), data.size());

    ASSERT_EQ(data[13], 3);

    // Client Hello, with cookie
    BIO_write(client_rbio, data.data(), data.size());
    SSL_do_handshake(client);
    data_len = BIO_ctrl_pending(client_wbio);
    data.resize(data_len);
    BIO_read(client_wbio, data.data(), data.size());

    ASSERT_EQ(data[13], 1);

    // Should be pass...?
    BIO_write(server_rbio, data.data(), data.size());
    ASSERT_EQ(DTLSv1_listen(server, NULL), 1);
}
```

The last assert fails -- it is -1 in this example, 0 in my actual code (and subsequent BIO_read gets me data[13]=3 aka HelloVerifyRequest) but the important thing to note here is that if you attach a debugger and put a breakpoint on the verification lambda it will not be hit.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out. I'm running into the same problem. I looked over the source for `DTLSv1_listen` and AFAICT it should be able to process the ClientHello *with* the cookie just fine...

Comment: I never did get to the bottom of this, unfortunately. I tried joining the OpenSSL mailing list to ask the folks there but the process proved cumbersome and I never got an answer.

Comment: I ended up getting it to work. In my case, I *had* to pass a valid `BIO_ADDR` to `DTLSv1_listen` despite what the documentation says. I'll try to remember to go through my code in case there was something else I forgot...

Comment: That's awesome! If you get the chance to look back at, please post as an answer and I'll confirm and mark it accepted!

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to de-mystify the CLIENT_HELLO - HELLO_VERIFY_REQUEST

[RFC6347 - Denial-of-Service Countermeasures](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6347#section-4.2.1)

explains, that, though a CLIENT_HELLO may be spoofed, a HELLO_VERIFY_REQUEST is used to proof, that the client really listen the address. Therefore the server creates a cookie, using the data from the CLIENT_HELLO, the client IP-address and port, and a server secret.

> Cookie = HMAC(Secret, Client-IP, Client-Parameters)

The server doesn’t store that cookie, otherwise a mass spoofing would require a lot of memory. Therefore the server recalculates the cookie every time, a CLIENT_HELLO is received. If the CLIENT_HELLO contains a cookie, that is compared against the newly calculated one.
That new calculated cookie may now differ, if the CLIENT_HELLO  has changed anything else then the cookie. That includes, that also the client IP (address+port) must be unchanged. The cookie may in some rare cases also differ, if the server updates his secret according the recommendation of RFC6347

> One potential attack on this scheme is for the attacker to collect a
> number of cookies from different addresses and then reuse them to
> attack the server.  The server can defend against this attack by
> changing the Secret value frequently, thus invalidating those cookies.

With that, check, if your CLIENT_HELLO is changed (may be just the source-port is changed), or the server updates the secret too frequently.
If you can provide some wireshark captures, I may assist you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [nodejs-dtls](https://github.com/mobius-software-ltd/nodejs-dtls)

Sample usage can be found in
[IOTBroker. cloud nodejs client](https://github.com/mobius-software-ltd/iotbroker.cloud-nodejs-client)

Take a look at CoAP and MQTT-SN protocols

BR

Yulian Oifa

[Mobius Software](https://www.mobius-software.com)

Comment: This is definitely an alternative but not really what I'm looking for. I'd like to leverage the OpenSSL shipped with node.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, you *have* to provide a `BIO_addr` to `DTLSv1_listen`. In your case, you are passing `NULL`. I also thought this would work, but alas, it does not!